# What kind of Sealer for particle board

Tags: wood, seal

I have an early 80's oak vanity in the master bath. I think the sides and bottom of the drawers are some kind of particle board. Little pieces of wood pieces/dust are constantly present. I want to seal the drawers so they don't 'shed'. What is the best product to use for this? Thank you to anyone with an answer!

Mary

Answer (score 1):

Polyurethane is the modern standby product. Water-based is easier to work with, but oil-based is more durable.

One coat, steel wool, another coat or two. Keep 'em light to minimize runs.

Comment: +1 But no steel wool with water-based products. (and there are arguments as to whether water-based is less durable).

Comment: I've never had issues using steel wool with water-based urethane. I suppose a critical step is dust removal.

Comment: Exactly. And I have missed a few splinters and paid for it with stains.